# Play flip--flop

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

Flip flop is a memory / arithmetic game that I played in high school. Some number of players stand in a circle. The players take turns. On the `n`th turn, the current player checks:

1. What is the largest power of 7 dividing n?
2. How many instances of the digit 7 does the decimal representation of n contain?
3. What is the largest power of 8 dividing n?
4. How many instances of the digit 8 does the decimal representation of n contain?

Let `FLIPS(n)` be the sum of the power of 7 dividing `n` and the number of `7`'s n contains. For example, `FLIPS(7)=2` (divisible by 7 once, contains one 7), `FLIPS(14) = 1` (divisible by 7 once, contains zero 7's), `FLIPS(17)=1` (not divisible by 7, contains one 7).

Let `FLOPS(n)` be the sum of the power of 8 dividing `n` and the number of `8`'s `n` contains.

On a player's turn, if `FLIPS(n)=FLOPS(n)=0` they say `n`. Otherwise, they first say "flip" `FLIPS(n)` times and then say "flop" `FLOPS(n)` times.

If `FLIPS(n)` is odd, the direction of play swaps (from counterclockwise to clockwise or from clockwise to counterclockwise). The next `FLOPS(n)` players in the new play order are skipped.

### Task

Write a program that takes a pair of integers `(num_players, turns)` and plays Flipflop with a group of `num_players` players for `turns` turns. Output should be a list of the `current_player` on the nth turn. The players are numbered 1 through num_players. The player to the left of player 1 is player num_players. (If it's more convenient to label the players `0` to `num_players - 1`, that is fine too.) Play begins with player 1 in counterclockwise order.

### Example:

I'll give an example with 5 players. For the first 6 turns nothing interesting happens:

1. Player 1 says "1" (CCW)
2. Player 2 says "2" (CCW)

...

5. Player 5 says "5" (CCW)
6. Player 1 says "6" (CCW)
7. Player 2 says "flipflip" (still CCW `FLIPS(7)=2` is even)
8. Player 3 says "flopflop" (CCW, skip players 4 and 5)
9. Player 1 says "9" (CCW)

...

14. Player 1 says "flip" (now CW play order)
15. Player 5 says "15"   (CW)
16. Player 4 says "flop" (CW)
17. Player 2 says "flip" (now CCW)
18. Player 3 says "flop" (CCW)
19. Player 5 says "19"   (CCW)

The 70's and 80's have a lot of activity. When trying to actually play this game, it is hard to remember where in this 20 digit sequence you are (though 700 / 800 is much worse).

69. Player 4 says "69" (CW)
70. Player 3 says "flipflip" (still CW)
71. Player 2 says "flip"     (CCW)
72. Player 3 says "flipflop" (CW)
73. Player 1 says "flip"     (CCW)
74. Player 2 says "flip"     (CW)
75. Player 1 says "flip"     (CCW)
76. Player 2 says "flip"     (CW)
77. Player 1 says "flipflipflip"(CCW)
78. Player 2 says "flipflop"  (CW)
79. Player 5 says "flip"      (CCW)
80. Player 1 says "flopflop"  (CCW)
81. Player 4 says "flop"      (CCW)
82. Player 1 says "flop"      (CCW)
83. Player 3 says "flop"      (CCW)
84. Player 5 says "flipflop"  (CW)
85. Player 3 says "flop"      (CW)
86. Player 1 says "flop"      (CW)
87. Player 4 says "flipflop"  (CCW)
88. Player 1 says "flopflopflop"(CCW)
89. Player 5 says "flop"      (CCW)
90. Player 2 says "90"        (CCW)

### Scoring

This is code golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test Cases:

```
[2,100] => {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1}
[3,100] => {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,2,3,1,3,1,2,1,3,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,1,3,1,3,2,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,3,2,1,2,2,3,1,3,1,3,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,3,2,1,2,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,2,1,3,2,3,1,3,1}
[4,100] => {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,3,4,1,2,3,4,3,2,4,1,3,4,1,4,3,2,4,3,2,3,1,4,3,2,4,3,2,3,4,3,1,4,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,3,1,4,2,1,4,3,2,3,2,3,4,3,1,4,3,4,2,3,2,3,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,3,1,2,1,4,3,2,1,3,4,2,3}
[5,100] => {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,5,4,2,3,5,1,2,1,5,4,2,1,5,1,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,3,4,3,1,5,3,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,3,2,5,4,3,2,1,2,5,1,2,1,4,3,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,5,1,4,1,3,5,3,1,4,1,5,2,3,2,1,5,4,3,1,2,4,5}
[6,100] => {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,5,6,1,2,3,4,3,2,6,1,3,4,5,4,3,2,6,5,4,5,3,2,1,6,4,3,2,3,4,3,1,6,4,3,4,5,6,1,2,1,4,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,5,4,2,1,6,5,4,5,2,3,4,3,1,6,5,6,4,5,4,5,4,5,3,4,1,3,5,1,5,3,1,3,1,3,4,3,2,1,6,5,3,4,6,1}
[7,100] => {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,4,5,6,7,1,2,1,7,5,6,1,2,3,2,1,7,5,4,3,4,2,1,7,6,4,3,2,3,4,3,1,7,5,4,5,6,7,1,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,7,6,5,7,6,4,3,2,1,7,1,4,5,6,5,3,2,1,2,7,1,7,1,7,1,6,7,3,5,7,2,7,5,3,5,2,4,5,4,3,2,1,7,5,6,1,2}
```

### A picture

I had 100 players play the game for \$200^2\$ steps, made it into a 200 by 200 square and colored the squares by hue. Made with Mathematica.

[image: Hue map of flip flop]

Comment: @Arnauld I will add largest e.g., "What is the largest power of p dividing n?" but 1 is p^0, so that would be the zeroth power.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>35</s> 22 bytes

```
Dċ¥+ọɗþ7,8Ä-*Ɗ‘ƭ€P1;Ä%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//RMSLwqUr4buNyZfDvjcsOMOELSrGiuKAmMat4oKsUDE7w4Ql////MTAw/zc)

A dyadic link that takes the number of turns as the left argument and number of players as the right. Players and numbered from 0 to *number of players - 1* and play starts with player 1. Currently returns the start player and the current player after each turn (so 101 players in total); this could easily be changed to omit the final one at the cost of a byte.

As a bonus, [here's a version](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDC1UfNe473P6oceuh3Q93bDq05OGubqUot0dNa06sV/JSAUoCVT1qmJv1aOM6rsMtulrHuh41zDi2FqggwND6cIvqw53TuFyOdB9aqv1wd@/J6Yf3metYHF5@dM/hjSenP2rcCdSteWg50JiHO1oeNe561LgFas/RPUATH@7qAxrkDcRHpmUBSaA6PYXI//8f7lzrcHj5oaX/DQ0M/psDAA) that prints the player and what they say.

### Explanation

```
     ɗþ7,8              | Outer table using the following as a dyad and [7,8] as the rught argument (and 1..number of turbs as left argument)
  ¥                     | - Following as a dyad
D                       |   - Convert to decimal digits
 ċ                      |   - Count (right argument)
   +                    | - Add to
    ọ                   |   - Order (power of right argument that exactly divides left argument)
             ƭ€         | Alternate between the following:
           Ɗ            | - For first list (flips), following as a monad:
        Ä               |   - Cumulative sum
         -*             |   - -1 to the power of this
            ‘           | - For second list (flops) add 1
                 P      | Product (flips × flops)
                  1;    | Prepend 1
                    Ä   | Cumulative sum
                     %  | Modulo number of players
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>121 117</s>  115 bytes

Takes input as `(players)(turns)`. The output is 0-indexed.

```javascript
P=>T=>(F=p=>++t>T?[]:[p%P,...F(p+(g=(x,n=t)=>n%x?(t+g).split(x).length:1+g(x,n/x))(8)*(d*=g(7)&1||-1)+P)])(t=0,d=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcq7rsIwDADQna/oAtjEhIa3uHKYYO7AVnWo@ghFlRPR6KoD/17Emc@r/C@H6t2FuBZfN1PLU8b2wRbuHNgqFe3jmheXPMwz0lrfIShwDCMJR2Qr8/EKUTnUQ@i7CCPqvhEXnxej3G9tRkQ44wrqFTs44cJ8PmuDKsMCIXJKNRuc/vIt7WhPBzrSqdCtf9/K6gmSsJ0lSeVl8H2je@9AKGlBEEyaon75TmBJS8QZTl8) (raw output)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hco9b8IwEADQnV/hhXKHDzcGWhDozFTmDGxRhigfJig9W8SqMvDfU7Vvfo/qpxrrZx/TRkLTzh3PObsbO7hyZKd1crdLUZ6KuMzJGHOFqMEzTCSckJ0spwsk7dGMcegTTGiGVny6n6z2f@t9QoQjrqFZs4cDvtnXa2NR51giJM6oYYvzudjSjvb0QZ90KE0Xnl9VfQdR7BZK1UHGMLRmCB6EVAeCYLMMzXcV/48SpZVF8wi9wIpWiAucfwE) (post-processing for 1-indexed output)

#### Commented

```javascript
P => T => (                   // P = number of players, T = number of turns
  F = p =>                    // F = recursive function taking the current player ID p
    ++t > T ?                 // increment the turn ID; if it's greater than T:
      []                      //   stop recursion
    :                         // else:
      [                       //   update the output array:
        p % P,                //     append the current player ID
        ...F(                 //     append the result of a recursive call:
          p + (               //       update p ...
            g = (x,           //         g is a helper function taking x = 7 or 8
                    n = t) => //         and a counter n initialized to t
              n % x ?         //         if x is not a divisor of n:
                (t + g)       //           coerce t to a string
                .split(x)     //           and count the number of occurrences of x
                .length       //           plus 1
              :               //         else:
                1 +           //           increment the result
                g(x, n / x)   //           recursive call with n / x
          )(8) * (            //       invoke g(8) = FLOPS(t) + 1
            d *= g(7) & 1     //         leave d unchanged if g(7) = FLIPS(t) + 1 is odd
                 || -1        //         otherwise, update d to -d
          ) + P               //       make sure that p remains positive
        )                     //     end of recursive call
      ]                       //   end of output update
)(t = 0, d = 1)               // initial call to F with p = t = 0 and d = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 143 bytes

```python
def f(P,m):r=[];p=0;d=i=1;exec"r+=[p%P];d*=g(i,7)%2*2-1;p+=d*g(i,8);i+=1;"*m;return r
g=lambda n,b,k=1:n%b**k<1and g(n,b,k+1)or`n`.count(`b`)+k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7RioMwEHzvV4SCYJLtYaLWo2n@oe8iqI1a8Ywh2HL39Z7GWnzYsDM7MxnzNz4GzadJVTWq/Rv0@GJlmgkjA6FkK5mofqv70VKZGu@WCUVk47eQYI8TfmLCUKnIwnxj0dJZfiS9sNX4tBrZQyN/ir5UBdJQQifZRXslId2VFVqhxncsZXiwuc6/7sNTj35e5ph2k7GtHudGCbAgwAcH1xelL8pQPVj0Qq3@SLLtyoBDCBHEcIb5tNv4PIlDq2bDkdOv6OzQmhB@7vuE@K1Y1fHOw3b/xW@GO26bJSV0Hu6Sl507R7Tr4/pl0z8)

Input in `P` number of players, `m` rounds. Output is 0 indexed.

The function `g(n,b)` returns `flips(n)+1` or `flops(n)+1` with `b=7,8`, respectively. That `+1` saves a byte or three...

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 64 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔⁰ε≔¹δＦＮ«⟦Ｉ﹪εθ⟧≦⊕ιＦ⁺№Ｉι7№Ｅ↨ι⁷﹪ιＸ⁷⊕λ⁰≦±δ≧⁺×δ⊕⁺№Ｉι8№Ｅ↨ι⁸﹪ιＸ⁸⊕λ⁰ε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZA9a8MwEIbn@FccmU6ggjsUu3RqM2VIMKVb6aDaF0cgS4k@2qH0t6tXO@AUXA0H74l77pHao/KtUybnrT2luE/DO3k8i4fiMQTdWywl0JxuJXScDs4DXg8IAV/FqvHaRnzdqBBx57pkHJKEsxBvPLPaqdOFsrWtp4FspE6C/r0bgY1JATcuMWNEaCFhXa25Tk0G4JMKhFpCxd3LCk6N@2SJSsIVGY3gI6HkCvPuPfUq0vSMWelZ98c4Ckh40QMF7P7CFt3qZbd6wa3@101MH/yd811xX@abD/MD) Link is to verbose version of code. Players are 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the number of players.

```
≔⁰ε
```

Set the current player to player 0.

```
≔¹δ
```

Set the initial direction of play.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Loop for the given number of turns.

```
⟦Ｉ﹪εθ⟧
```

Output the current player.

```
≦⊕ι
```

1-index the current turn.

```
Ｆ⁺№Ｉι7№Ｅ↨ι⁷﹪ιＸ⁷⊕λ⁰
```

Count the number of flips.

```
≦±δ
```

Reverse the direction of play for each flip.

```
≧⁺×δ⊕⁺№Ｉι8№Ｅ↨ι⁸﹪ιＸ⁸⊕λ⁰ε
```

Calculate the next player to play.

Bonus 91-byte version outputs what each player says too:

```
Ｎθ≔⁰ε≔¹δＦＮ«≦⊕ι≔⁺№Ｉι7№Ｅ↨ι⁷﹪ιＸ⁷⊕λ⁰η≔⁺№Ｉι8№Ｅ↨ι⁸﹪ιＸ⁸⊕λ⁰ζ⟦⪫⟦⊕﹪εθ∨⁺×flipη×flopζι⟧:⟧≧×Ｘ±¹ηδ≧⁺×δ⊕ζε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHBS8MwFMbP61/x6OkFInQHadWT7jRhs4i3sUNsszaQJl2SKkz822tiu1mhYg4P3pcv3@8lKWpmCs1k369V27lt17xyg0dyF91bKyqFCQX@0y0plL47aAM4PUAIfESLDWtH31oVhjdcOV5SEP7EYtzIZWdxpTvlcMWsQ0EoxGns6yD6CHxglqOgkHp1o8tO6tDl@t2DUgqTbJTELwpJKPV/mGwek81gsr8xp4DJjfApu0ctFO6mzjGIUzgG85MZRnkRDbcYH6Ro4zAphYuig3IKZkH2fsrbmOwD4vKYz6Kq3ZBwHm/LK@Y4LsmQVc74A/ZMKX/f5hsWPvWz76@jm6S/epNf) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 26 bytes

```
ƛ78fMƛ÷₍ǑO∑;;∩÷›u„¦e*¦Ȯ%0p
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGmzc4Zk3Gm8O34oKNx5FP4oiROzviiKnDt+KAunXigJ7CpmUqwqbIriUwcCIsIiIsIjEwMFxuNyJd)

Pretty much a port of [Nick Kennedy's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197271/103205). First argument `turns-1`, second argument `num_players`, players are zero-indexed.

### How?

```
                           #                 e.g. stack (top ->)
ƛ78fMƛ÷₍ǑO∑;;∩÷›u„¦e*¦Ȯ%0p #                      100
ƛ                          # for i = 1..turns     77
 78f                       #   push, split        77 [7,8]
    M                      #   pair               [77,7] [77,8]
     ƛ                     #   for [i,7] [i,8]    [77,7]
      ÷                    #     split            77 7
       ₍                   #     parallel apply
        Ǒ                  #       multiplicity   1     
         O                 #       count          2
                           #     end              [1,2]
          ∑                #     sum              3
           ;               #   end                [3,0]
            ;              # end                  [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],...]
             ∩             # transpose            [[0,0,0,...],[0,0,0,...]]
              ÷            # split                [0,0,0,...] [0,0,0,...]
               ›           # increment            [0,0,0,...] [1,1,1,...]
                u          # push -1              [0,0,0,...] [1,1,1,...] -1
                 „         # rotate left          [1,1,1,...] -1 [0,0,0,...]
                  ¦        # prefix sum           [1,1,1,...] -1 [0,0,0,...]
                   e       # exponent             [1,1,1,...] [1,1,1,...]
                    *      # multiply             [1,1,1,...]
                     ¦     # prefix sum           [1,2,3,...]
                      Ȯ    # over                 [1,2,3,...] 3
                       %   # modulo               [1,2,0,...]
                        0p # prepend 0            [0,1,2,...]
```